# Global generic value in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin

Given the simple class:

```
data class Optional<T>(val value: T?)
```

I can define generic function and value **extensions** as follows:

```
fun <T> T?.makeOptional() = Optional(this)  // Compiles ✅
val <T> T?.optional get() = Optional(this) // Compiles ✅
```

I can also define **global** generic functions:

```
fun <T> makeOptionalNull() : Optional<T> = Optional(null) // Compiles ✅
```

However I CAN'T define an equivalent **global** generic value to this last function:

```
val <T> optionalNull : Optional<T> = Optional(null) // Compilation Error ❌
//   ^ Type parameter of a property must be used in its receiver type
```

A **global** non-generic value is totally fine though:

```
val stringNull : Optional<String> = Optional(null) // Compiles ✅
```

How can I create a global generic value similar to the one above? Is it even possible?

Comment: Properties can't have generic types unless the type is parameter of the class. That's impossible with a global property.

Comment: What type would `T` be in the `optionalNull` case?  (The _value_ may not depend upon it, but its _type_ does.  And you have no way to specify `T` when calling it.)

Comment: @gidds `T` can be specified and inferred by the compiler when calling it for example like this: `var myString : Optional<String> = optionalNull`. Actually right now I have something similar that works using the global generic function instead: `var defaultString: Optional<String> = makeOptionalNull()` and
`var defaultInt: Optional<Int> = makeOptionalNull()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be solved the following way:

```
data class Optional<out T>(val value: T?) // <- note the 'out' modifier here

val optionalNull: Optional<Nothing> = Optional(null)

// and use it as follows:
val myOptionalVariable: Optional<String> = optionalNull // assignable thanks to 'out' modifier
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Declaration-site variance is indeed the way to go, thanks!